# What is the Type of FormGroup.Controls?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular formGroup named: "form" with controls and i can access the array of the control by using the statement "`this.form.controls;`".

i want to add a variable named "formControls" as reference to the "form.controls".
`const formControls = this.form.controls;` works ok but i want to add the time of  this.form.controls for the intellisense.

The definition of the Angular FormGroup class is:

```
export declare class FormGroup extends AbstractControl {
controls: {
    [key: string]: AbstractControl;
};
constructor(controls: {
    [key: string]: AbstractControl;
}, validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null, asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null);
```

Comment: _but i want to add the time of this.form.controls for the intellisense._ I dont understand...

Comment: The answer is in the question. The type is `{
    [key: string]: AbstractControl;
}`.

Comment: Are you looking for `formControls:FormControl[]`?

Comment: @JBNizet i think you right! i didn't notice to the fact that i can use type like this. i used to specify specific class name as the type...